Conformal map a quarter disc into a horizontal strip
I'm interested in mapping the quarter disk $\{z = x+iy \in \mathbb{C}: 0 < x < 1, 0 <y<1  \}$, i.e. the intersection of $\mathbb{D}$ with the first quadrant to the horizontal strip $\{z=x+iy \in \mathbb{C}: x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in (0,10) \}$
First, define $T_1(z) = z^2$. This map turns the quarter disk into an upper half disk. Then define $T_2(z) = \frac{1+z}{1-z}$. As $-1$ runs to $1$, $0$ runs to $\infty$ and we know that this becomes the positive real-axis because $T_2(0) = 1$ and explicitly if $z=x+iy$,
$$T_2(z) = \frac{1-(x^2+y^2)}{(1-x)^2+y^2} + i \frac{2y}{(1-x)^2+y^2}$$
keeping the region in the first quadrant. Next, we extend the first quadrant to the upper half plane with the map $T_3(z)= z^2$ again. Then using the branch of the logarithm that deletes the negative real axis, $T_4(z) = T_4(re^{i \theta}) = \log re^{i \theta} = \log |r| + i \theta$ turns the upper half plane into the horizontal strip
$$\{z =x+iy \in \mathbb{C}: x \in \mathbb{R}, y \in (0,\pi)\}$$
Finally, we stretch the strip up to $y=10$ via the map $T_5(z) = \frac{10}{\pi}\cdot z$
Did I make any errors or slight missteps? I'm interested in particular in my use of the logarithm since branch cuts have never made sense to me.
